# Textbox input on win 7 touch screen : does it need an onscreen keyboard?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, touchscreen

I have a (partial)touchscreen app with a textbox in it. Users should be able to input text without a keyboard.

Now because I can't test touchscreen yet, I have a question about the normal behavior in Win 7 : When you click (touch) the textbox, is there an onscreen keyboard shown automatically, or is only the caret blinking in the textbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a bit a development for Windows 7 using a touchscreen. The virtual keyboard is launched by default (I haven't installed the system so I don't know if it was enabled by default). When I clicked on a `textbox` of one of my application (or on any other applications) the virtual keyboard appeared on the screen.

So hopefully you should be fine.